# getreadabledatabase throws null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

In my android project i have a database, and i can access it using `getReadableDatabase()` after installing the app and launching the app for the first time.But if the app is closed and re-opened. `getReadableDatabase()` throwing `NullPointerException`. can anyone tell me why this is happening. here is my code

```
 public static int getQuestionCount(){
    String sql ="Select*from QuestionAndAnswer";
    SQLiteDatabase database = sqlLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

the error is throwing in the third line `SQLiteDatabase database = sqlLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();` i can see the database in the ddms device monitor  can anyone suggest a way to fix this.

Comment: try using  this.getReadableDatabase(); and also make sure you have data inside your table If this function is inside a class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: the method is static and this cannot be used in static context and the class containing this method is a wrapper class to the sqlitehelper class. Changed the static method to a normal method and that helped

Comment: Can you provide you Logcat error lines

Comment: the problem is fixed.thanks for your time

Comment: `NullPointerException`